# Interface of a parameter of (change) event in Angular

Tags: angular, events

Which interface should I use to avoid *any* type as parameter?

As an Example:
I have html file

```
<div>
    <mat-button-toggle-group (change)="onToggleChange($event);">
        <mat-button-toggle>
            something
        </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group 
</div>
```

and TS

```
onToggleChange(event): void {
  console.log(event.value)
}
```

If I'm using it like that, it'd work in the browser and I could get the value. I'd like to avoid *any* type. If I'm trying following

```
onToggleChange(event): void {
  console.log(event.value)
}
```

I'll get an error in text editor but in browser all will be fine. I can't find any type that I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event emitter is of the type [`MatButtonToggleChange`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button-toggle/button-toggle.ts#L213). Try the following if you need to specify the type

```js
import { MatButtonToggleChange } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';

export class ButtonToggleExclusiveExample {
  onToggleChange(event: MatButtonToggleChange): void {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

However if you need only the value from the event, you could bind to the [`valueChange`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button-toggle/button-toggle.ts#L186) event emitter. It is of type `any`.

Template

```html
<div>
  <mat-button-toggle-group (valueChange)="onToggleChange($event);">
    <mat-button-toggle>
      something
    </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

Controller

```js
export class ButtonToggleExclusiveExample {
  onToggleChange(event: any): void {
    console.log(event);    // <-- prints the value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MatButtonToggleModule` type.
Here is the docs for that: https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it. I was skimming through the docs and missed it. Thanks a lot though!